# Create a new lis in an array and then sum their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sum

My team is working on a web application to display personal finances. 
We would like the user to add their spendings with the matching category (e.g. $50 for food) and make those entries lis. We then want to take the sum of, for example, all the food entries and display it. So we need to somehow get those lis in arrays - that's what I think. And somehow the new lis, which are not there yet, must have some special id (?) so they "find" each other (meaning, all food values go to the food array)? And is there a way to do it with React?

I'm not sure how to integrate React and how to form arrays to sum the values (here "wert") later.

Kategorie hinzufügen: add category
  Zahlenwert hinzufügen: add value
  dropdown: where you can choose categories
  wert: where you insert the spent value
  eingabeNum: insertedNum
  eingabeText: insertedText

```js
function grab(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        var eingabeNum = $("#wert").val();
        var eingabeText = $("#dropdown").val();
        if (eingabeNum == "" || eingabeText == "") {
            alert("Bitte alle spalten ausfüllen!");
        } else {
            $("#wert").val("");
            $("#dropdown").val("Kategorie");
            $("ul").append("<li><span class='trash'><i class='fa fa- 
                trash '></i></span> " + eingabeText + "<span 
                class = 'betrag' > " + eingabeNum + "€ < /span></li > ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Jquery instead of react. And your question is not really clear to me. What do you mean by `create new lis in an array`? What is `lis`?

Comment: i think, it's all `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using React (you're appending new elements with jQuery). So if you're just working with DOM elements you could include a CSS class on each element `<li class="food">..</li>`. Then you could select them easily `$("li.food")`.

You also need the value of the element. You could navigate from the `li` to the `span` that contains the value and get it from there, but it's getting pretty messy. Maybe it would be cleaner to include the item value as a HTML attribute:

```
$("ul").append("<li class='food' itemValue='" + eingabeNum + "'><span class='trash'><i class='fa fa- 
            trash '></i></span> " + eingabeText + "<span 
            class = 'betrag' > " + eingabeNum + "€ < /span></li > ")
```

Then you could easily get it from the `<li>`.

```
let sum = 0;
$("li.food").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).attr("itemValue");
});
console.log("Sum of food items: " + sum);
```